# Trouble with commit in a postgres procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to convert some Oracle Stored procedures to Postgres and I'm confused on the rules for using commit.

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_example(
        start_date character varying,
        rgn_nm character varying)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare
        startdate date;
        c_rec record;
        c_cur CURSOR(begindate DATE, rgn VARCHAR) for
            SELECT 
              region, 
              WR_ID AS wrid         
         FROM ORDERS
         where feed_dt=begindate 
         and region=rgn;    
begin
        startdate       := TO_DATE (start_date, 'YYYYMMDD');
    
        delete from ORDER_ARCHIVE where STATE_RGN_ID=rgn_nm;
        commit;
        
        open c_cur(startdate, rgn_nm);
        
        loop
            fetch c_cur into c_rec;
            
            exit when not found;
           INSERT
               INTO ORDER_ARCHIVE (
                    STATE_RGN_ID,
                    WRID                                                                                                 
             )  
             VALUES (
                    c_rec.region,
                    c_rec.WRID                                                                          
                   ); 
                   
        end loop;       
        
        close c_cur;
        
        commit;
        
    end;
    $BODY$;
```

I'm getting errors like this no matter where I put the commits:

```
ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function sp_example(character varying,character varying) line 16 at COMMIT
SQL state: 2D000
```

Can you just not use commits inside stored procedures or am I just placing them in the wrong place or some other problem entirely? The Oracle procedures I'm converting have tons of commits in them so I can see this is going to be a bit of a challenge.

Comment: The docs are a good place to start [Transaction managment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html)

Comment: Should be obvious to disclose the version of Postgres in use.

Comment: I would simply remove the two `COMMIT`s. They seem pointless.